# Laravel model OR Laravel's way of working

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I have implemented MVC Model in php, now I am learning Laravel. Now while implementing mvc model in php used the following code in index.php:

```
$object = new controller_class;
$object->process();
```

but can somebody explain me how Laravel works? I mean the internal stuff. How it is managing all that stuff? I don't see any object of controller's class in Laravel.
Link to an article may also work!

Comment: Start [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/) and end [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel is based on the MVC architecture, however, it makes some "modifications" to the normal way of how MVCs work. I will suggest a few resources you can check, so you can get a broader view of what is happening:

- https://blog.pusher.com/laravel-mvc-use/
- https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/why-laravel-mvc-framework-you-should-forget-kali-dass/